# Conditional angular class and jQuery applying a function to an element containing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to apply a moment picker plugin written in jQuery, in an AngularJS application.

The thing is that this is an element that has been previously used as a text input.

So what I did was that I made conditional classes (using ng-class).

So my input looks like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{
    'datepicker': $ctrl.isDatepicker, 'timepicker': $ctrl.isTimepicker}" ng-model="$ctrl.model"
           ng-change="$ctrl.onChangeFunction()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}">
```

Then, in the directive, I am calling the jQuery functions like this:

```
        $('.datepicker').pickadate();
        $('.timepicker').pickatime();
```

The problem is that for some reason, the date/time pickers do not get applied.

I am inspecting the element, and the class is being correctly applied (based on the conditions).

If I make the datepicker/timepicker class static (not conditional), then the jQuery functions do get applied (but then all my text inputs become date pickers, so this is not an option, unless I create two new directives, with static classes).

So I was thinking that maybe they get called before things are loaded.

For this, I have tried two ways, unsuccessfully:

1. call the two jQuery functions in an `ng-init`.
2. Call the two jQuery functions like this:

   ```
   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
       $('.datepicker').pickadate();
       $('.timepicker').pickatime();
   });
   ```

Can anybody point me in the right direction and possibly tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Can you try calling the two jQuery functions in a `$timeout`?

Comment: I hesitated to do that because it seems more of a workaround, than a solution, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Seeing as it works, I'll leave it like this for now, thx.